# ¿How to deal with virtual methods when trying to create COM class?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, vb6, interop, virtual-functions

I'm trying to create a COM class in .Net to interop with VB6. The idea is to integrate Crystal Reports in a .Net library and so this one can be consumed in VB6. As far as I've gotten, some methods are working in the VB6 enviroment, but when I try to execute a method which uses a virutal function, the application stops working (freezes).

This is the virtual method:
    `public virtual void SetDataSource(DataSet dataSet);`
which has 4 overloads.

This is the method that I execute from VB6:

```
public void fillReportWithDataSet(ReportDocument pReport, DataSet pDataSet)
{
    pReport.SetDataSource(pDataSet); // Virtual Function
}
```

When I execute other methods which have overloads, it still works, but these overloaded methods aren't virtual. ¿Why does it stop working? ¿Which is the right way to use this method?

Thanks

Comment: In C# if the method isn't virtual, then aren't you overRIDING it, not overLOADING it? That seems like a key difference.